# LINQ to SQL - Dead Lock on Insert

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, database-deadlocks

I am facing deadlock issue on SQL Server -2014 standard edition. Two inserts are getting deadlocked over a clustered index.

It is an OLTP database and table is high insert and high read, table already has primary key with clustered index and having more that 13 Million records

[image: DeadLock Graph]

The SQL Statements are given below

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[PatientBilledItem]([PatientBillUID], [EventOccuredDttm], [ServiceName], [BillableItemUID], [Amount], [CUser], [CWhen], [MUser], [MWhen], [StatusFlag], [OwnerOrganisationUID], [PatientBillableItemUID], [Discount], [NetAmount], [Description], [Comments], [ItemMultiplier], [BSMDDUID], [ItemName], [DiscountAuthorizedBy], [ConsultantShare], [ServiceTax], [CareProviderUID], [QNUOMUID], [SpecialAmount], [IsRefunded], [ConsultantDiscount], [EducationCess], [HigherEducationCess], [RecordedByUID], [OriginalCreditBillUID], [PatientPackageItemUID], [BatchID], [VATPercentage], [InternalCost], [CalculateTaxOnMRP], [StoreUID], [BillPackageUID], [SplitDiscount], [RSLVLUID], [ParentUID], [PackageItemAmount], [RoundOff], [AuthNo], [ExpiryDttm], [BILGRDUID], [ApprovalCode], [ApprovedBy], [InternalBatchID])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31, @p32, @p33, @p34, @p35, @p36, @p37, @p38, @p39, @p40, @p41, @p42, @p43, @p44, @p45, @p46, @p47, @p48)

SELECT [t0].[UID], [t0].[TIMESTAMP]
FROM [dbo].[PatientBilledItem] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[UID] = (SCOPE_IDENTITY())',N'@p0 bigint,@p1 datetime,@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 int,@p4 float,@p5 int,@p6 datetime,@p7 int,@p8 datetime,@p9 nvarchar(4000),@p10 int,@p11 bigint,@p12 float,@p13 float,@p14 nvarchar(4000),@p15 nvarchar(4000),@p16 float,@p17 int,@p18 nvarchar(4000),@p19 int,@p20 float,@p21 float,@p22 int,@p23 int,@p24 float,@p25 nvarchar(4000),@p26 float,@p27 float,@p28 float,@p29 int,@p30 bigint,@p31 bigint,@p32 nvarchar(4000),@p33 float,@p34 float,@p35 nvarchar(4000),@p36 int,@p37 int,@p38 float,@p39 int,@p40 bigint,@p41 float,@p42 float,@p43 nvarchar(4000),@p44 datetime,@p45 int,@p46 nvarchar(4000),@p47 int,@p48 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=3796014,@p1='2017-06-20 12:12:49.300',@p2=N'Consultancy',@p3=38328,@p4=500,@p5=4985,@p6='2017-06-20 12:13:12.603',@p7=4985,@p8='2017-06-20 12:13:12.603',@p9=N'A',@p10=4,@p11=10692556,@p12=NULL,@p13=500,@p14=NULL,@p15=NULL,@p16=1,@p17=1159,@p18=N'Dr. B K ',@p19=NULL,@p20=500,@p21=NULL,@p22=1395,@p23=NULL,@p24=NULL,@p25=NULL,@p26=NULL,@p27=NULL,@p28=NULL,@p29=NULL,@p30=NULL,@p31=NULL,@p32=NULL,@p33=NULL,@p34=NULL,@p35=NULL,@p36=NULL,@p37=NULL,@p38=NULL,@p39=NULL,@p40=NULL,@p41=NULL,@p42=NULL,@p43=NULL,@p44=NULL,@p45=NULL,@p46=NULL,@p47=NULL,@p48=NULL


exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[PatientBilledItem]([PatientBillUID], [EventOccuredDttm], [ServiceName], [BillableItemUID], [Amount], [CUser], [CWhen], [MUser], [MWhen], [StatusFlag], [OwnerOrganisationUID], [PatientBillableItemUID], [Discount], [NetAmount], [Description], [Comments], [ItemMultiplier], [BSMDDUID], [ItemName], [DiscountAuthorizedBy], [ConsultantShare], [ServiceTax], [CareProviderUID], [QNUOMUID], [SpecialAmount], [IsRefunded], [ConsultantDiscount], [EducationCess], [HigherEducationCess], [RecordedByUID], [OriginalCreditBillUID], [PatientPackageItemUID], [BatchID], [VATPercentage], [InternalCost], [CalculateTaxOnMRP], [StoreUID], [BillPackageUID], [SplitDiscount], [RSLVLUID], [ParentUID], [PackageItemAmount], [RoundOff], [AuthNo], [ExpiryDttm], [BILGRDUID], [ApprovalCode], [ApprovedBy], [InternalBatchID])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31, @p32, @p33, @p34, @p35, @p36, @p37, @p38, @p39, @p40, @p41, @p42, @p43, @p44, @p45, @p46, @p47, @p48)

SELECT [t0].[UID], [t0].[TIMESTAMP]
FROM [dbo].[PatientBilledItem] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[UID] = (SCOPE_IDENTITY())',N'@p0 bigint,@p1 datetime,@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 int,@p4 float,@p5 int,@p6 datetime,@p7 int,@p8 datetime,@p9 nvarchar(4000),@p10 int,@p11 bigint,@p12 float,@p13 float,@p14 nvarchar(4000),@p15 nvarchar(4000),@p16 float,@p17 int,@p18 nvarchar(4000),@p19 int,@p20 float,@p21 float,@p22 int,@p23 int,@p24 float,@p25 nvarchar(4000),@p26 float,@p27 float,@p28 float,@p29 int,@p30 bigint,@p31 bigint,@p32 nvarchar(4000),@p33 float,@p34 float,@p35 nvarchar(4000),@p36 int,@p37 int,@p38 float,@p39 int,@p40 bigint,@p41 float,@p42 float,@p43 nvarchar(4000),@p44 datetime,@p45 int,@p46 nvarchar(4000),@p47 int,@p48 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=3796013,@p1='2017-06-20 12:13:10.030',@p2=N'Consultancy',@p3=83986,@p4=600,@p5=763,@p6='2017-06-20 12:13:12.023',@p7=763,@p8='2017-06-20 12:13:12.023',@p9=N'A',@p10=8,@p11=10692557,@p12=NULL,@p13=600,@p14=NULL,@p15=NULL,@p16=1,@p17=1159,@p18=N'Dr.L K S',@p19=NULL,@p20=600,@p21=NULL,@p22=1506,@p23=NULL,@p24=NULL,@p25=NULL,@p26=NULL,@p27=NULL,@p28=NULL,@p29=NULL,@p30=NULL,@p31=NULL,@p32=NULL,@p33=NULL,@p34=NULL,@p35=NULL,@p36=NULL,@p37=NULL,@p38=NULL,@p39=NULL,@p40=NULL,@p41=NULL,@p42=NULL,@p43=NULL,@p44=NULL,@p45=NULL,@p46=NULL,@p47=NULL,@p48=NULL
```

Yes the table is having trigger as well

The event XML is attached

```html
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="processa19016ca8" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="processa19016ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="3888" waitresource="KEY: 9:72057699966713856 (ffffffffffff)" waittime="1034" ownerId="1298235110" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-06-20T11:52:42.003" XDES="0x714fe0d90" lockMode="RangeI-N" schedulerid="1" kpid="7856" status="suspended" spid="66" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-06-20T11:52:42.830" lastbatchcompleted="2017-06-20T11:52:42.820" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.820" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WIN-2HO2RRV99BU" hostpid="2980" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="1298235110" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="1236" stmtend="3454" sqlhandle="0x0200000064f4502b431082b3ac55b13757583f58c2c98c7c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@p0 bigint,@p1 datetime,@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 int,@p4 float,@p5 int,@p6 datetime,@p7 int,@p8 datetime,@p9 nvarchar(4000),@p10 int,@p11 bigint,@p12 float,@p13 float,@p14 nvarchar(4000),@p15 nvarchar(4000),@p16 float,@p17 int,@p18 nvarchar(4000),@p19 int,@p20 float,@p21 float,@p22 int,@p23 int,@p24 float,@p25 nvarchar(4000),@p26 float,@p27 float,@p28 float,@p29 int,@p30 bigint,@p31 bigint,@p32 nvarchar(4000),@p33 float,@p34 float,@p35 nvarchar(4000),@p36 int,@p37 int,@p38 float,@p39 int,@p40 bigint,@p41 float,@p42 float,@p43 nvarchar(4000),@p44 datetime,@p45 int,@p46 nvarchar(4000),@p47 int,@p48 nvarchar(4000))INSERT INTO [dbo].[PatientBilledItem]([PatientBillUID], [EventOccuredDttm], [ServiceName], [BillableItemUID], [Amount], [CUser], [CWhen], [MUser], [MWhen], [StatusFlag], [OwnerOrganisationUID], [PatientBillableItemUID], [Discount], [NetAmount], [Description], [Comments], [ItemMultiplier], [BSMDDUID], [ItemName], [DiscountAuthorizedBy], [ConsultantShare], [ServiceTax], [CareProviderUID], [QNUOMUID], [Sp   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process18572db848" taskpriority="0" logused="3896" waitresource="KEY: 9:72057699966713856 (ffffffffffff)" waittime="1012" ownerId="1298235129" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-06-20T11:52:42.027" XDES="0x1ada4fed90" lockMode="RangeI-N" schedulerid="1" kpid="14928" status="suspended" spid="118" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-06-20T11:52:42.853" lastbatchcompleted="2017-06-20T11:52:42.847" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.847" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WIN-PGECRKPS51J" hostpid="3092" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="1298235129" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="1236" stmtend="3454" sqlhandle="0x0200000064f4502b431082b3ac55b13757583f58c2c98c7c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@p0 bigint,@p1 datetime,@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 int,@p4 float,@p5 int,@p6 datetime,@p7 int,@p8 datetime,@p9 nvarchar(4000),@p10 int,@p11 bigint,@p12 float,@p13 float,@p14 nvarchar(4000),@p15 nvarchar(4000),@p16 float,@p17 int,@p18 nvarchar(4000),@p19 int,@p20 float,@p21 float,@p22 int,@p23 int,@p24 float,@p25 nvarchar(4000),@p26 float,@p27 float,@p28 float,@p29 int,@p30 bigint,@p31 bigint,@p32 nvarchar(4000),@p33 float,@p34 float,@p35 nvarchar(4000),@p36 int,@p37 int,@p38 float,@p39 int,@p40 bigint,@p41 float,@p42 float,@p43 nvarchar(4000),@p44 datetime,@p45 int,@p46 nvarchar(4000),@p47 int,@p48 nvarchar(4000))INSERT INTO [dbo].[PatientBilledItem]([PatientBillUID], [EventOccuredDttm], [ServiceName], [BillableItemUID], [Amount], [CUser], [CWhen], [MUser], [MWhen], [StatusFlag], [OwnerOrganisationUID], [PatientBillableItemUID], [Discount], [NetAmount], [Description], [Comments], [ItemMultiplier], [BSMDDUID], [ItemName], [DiscountAuthorizedBy], [ConsultantShare], [ServiceTax], [CareProviderUID], [QNUOMUID], [Sp   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <keylock hobtid="72057699966713856" dbid="9" objectname="HEALTHOBJECT.dbo.PatientBilledItem" indexname="IX_PatientBillableItem" id="lock28bc25a00" mode="RangeS-S" associatedObjectId="72057699966713856">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process18572db848" mode="RangeS-S" />
    <owner id="process18572db848" mode="RangeI-N" requestType="convert" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="processa19016ca8" mode="RangeI-N" requestType="convert" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
  <keylock hobtid="72057699966713856" dbid="9" objectname="HEALTHOBJECT.dbo.PatientBilledItem" indexname="IX_PatientBillableItem" id="lock28bc25a00" mode="RangeS-S" associatedObjectId="72057699966713856">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="processa19016ca8" mode="RangeS-S" />
    <owner id="processa19016ca8" mode="RangeI-N" requestType="convert" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process18572db848" mode="RangeI-N" requestType="convert" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Add, also, the deadlock graph in XML format (right click > Extract event data as XML ...).

Comment: please add your insert statements

Comment: What SELECT statement(s) are executed on dbo.PatientBilledItem table by these two connections: 65 and 128 ? First guess: there are some missing indexes on this table. Check execution plan of queries / procedures executed by 65 and 128. There are triggers on this table ?

Comment: [Extract event data...](https://www.sqlshack.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/word-image-118.png)

Comment: Both 65 and 128 are simple insert statements

Comment: @SamsudeenB: SELECT statements ? Better, post SQL source code for both connections.

Comment: both event xml and  statements are update in the post

Comment: I'd also add the code for the trigger if I were you.

Comment: @SamsudeenB you don't need the SELECT statement, you can get the inserted values with the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: Please be careful when publish personally identifiable information. Don't do stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

INSERTs alone won't deadlock each other. If you call `SELECT WHERE UID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in the same transaction though, the server will have to take a SHARED lock on any indexes that contain UID. That's because you tried to read the value of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` which will change if another row is added, leading to inconsistent data. If you use the REPEATABLE READ isolation level, you could end up with a deadlock.

The solution is very easy - don't use a separate SELECT. You can use the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) of INSERT to get all the new values, like identity, default values etc :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PatientBilledItem] 
([PatientBillUID], [EventOccuredDttm], [ServiceName], [BillableItemUID], [Amount], [CUser], [CWhen], [MUser], [MWhen], [StatusFlag], [OwnerOrganisationUID], [PatientBillableItemUID], [Discount], [NetAmount], [Description], [Comments], [ItemMultiplier], [BSMDDUID], [ItemName], [DiscountAuthorizedBy], [ConsultantShare], [ServiceTax], [CareProviderUID], [QNUOMUID], [SpecialAmount], [IsRefunded], [ConsultantDiscount], [EducationCess], [HigherEducationCess], [RecordedByUID], [OriginalCreditBillUID], [PatientPackageItemUID], [BatchID], [VATPercentage], [InternalCost], [CalculateTaxOnMRP], [StoreUID], [BillPackageUID], [SplitDiscount], [RSLVLUID], [ParentUID], [PackageItemAmount], [RoundOff], [AuthNo], [ExpiryDttm], [BILGRDUID], [ApprovalCode], [ApprovedBy], [InternalBatchID])
OUTPUT inserted.UID,inserted.Timestamp
VALUES ......
```

You can combine this with the SNAPSHOT isolation level to reduce blocking between transactions.

Comment: The inserts are auto generated using LINQ also the isolaation settings are READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT

Comment: @SamsudeenB First, you should specify this explicitly. Second, LINQ doesnt' generate SQL, it's a generic query language. LINQ to what? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entities? What ORM version? What is the exact .NET code? Where is the *transaction* code?

Comment: what i mean is the insert is through LINQ to SQL

Comment: @SamsudeenB which is obsolete, without any new development for 7+ years. And won't be available in .NET Core either. Any fixes for such deadlocks were released with EF

Answer (score 0):

Based on provided info, first assumption is that these deadlocks are caused by one of following missing indexes

```
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ NONCLUSTERED INDEX IUN_PatientBilledItem_UID_#_TIMESTAMP
ON dbo.PatientBilledItem (UID)
INCLUDE(TIMESTAMP)
```

or

```
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ NONCLUSTERED INDEX IUN_PatientBilledItem_UID_TIMESTAMP
ON dbo.PatientBilledItem (UID, TIMESTAMP)
```

needed by following `SELECT` statements:

```
SELECT [t0].[UID], [t0].[TIMESTAMP] 
FROM [dbo].[PatientBilledItem] AS [t0] 
WHERE [t0].[UID] = (SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

which generate `RangeS-S` locks (also because TX isolation level is `SERIALIZABLE`).

Note: Uncomment `/*UNIQUE*/` keyword if current index has unique values or unique pair of values (compound index).